How to add paypal and google pay as customers payment method in stripe.js
In rails app I have Stripe API integration. On frontend part stripe.js library is imported and used to save/delete customer payment methods:
const stripe_key = 'pk_test_xxx';
const stripe = Stripe(stripe_key);

var elements = stripe.elements();
const paymentMethod = elements.create("card", { hidePostalCode: true })

When user enter valid card data I generate token which is send to rails backend and forward to Stripe API in order to save it as customers payment method:
 document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(paymentMethod);

            console.log(token, error)

            fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/payment_methods', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 
                    token: token.id,
                    is_default_payment_method: document.getElementById('set_as_default').checked
                })
            }).then(function(response) {
                if (response.ok) {
                    // Payment method saved successfully
                } else {
                    // Failed to save payment method
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });  

Now I wonder is possible to add payment methods like paypal or google pay. Can't find those types in documentation https://docs.stripe.com/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card

https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-methods/overview

You can see a comparison between the Card Element and Payment Element here : https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-card-element-comparison
The Card Element only supports accepting cards, and does not accept card payments using Wallets (e.g. Apple Pay, Google Pay).
If you want to accept other payment method types, you should use the Payment Element which allows you to accept multiple payment methods with a single integration. You can view the guides here :

https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/quickstart

If you don't want to use the Payment Element, you can consider integrating the Express Checkout Element (to display the wallets as payment method options) alongside with the Card Element : https://docs.stripe.com/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment
Also, Tokens are a legacy API. Tokens do not support many new features such as Strong Customer Authentication (e.g. 3DS). You should really be using PaymentMethods instead.

Thanks, I switched to Payment Element and was able to save card and paypal as payment options. Still struggel to save google and apple pay.
